# jQuery attr Select on Dropdown not working Mac Safari

Tags: jquery, macos, select, safari, attr

I have a snippet where a customer presses a button on the webpage.

This button should select an option in a hidden select box and update a few hidden fields on the page. It works on all platforms and browsers accept on Safari on the Mac.. the dropdown does not get updated.

Tracked it down to

```
$('#selectSize option[id=Bespoke]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

The dropdown does not update but everything else works - only on Safari on the Mac.

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/XPD25/10/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value) instead:

```
$('#selectSize option[id=Bespoke]').prop('selected', true);
```

Also, IDs are unique so there is no need for the additional bits in the selector:

```
$("#Bespoke").prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: This is a major bug for Safari and Mac devices. How do I report this to jQuery team and Safari team? Triggers issues on Chrome/Firefox as far as I know and `.prop()` seems best approach

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('#selectSize option[id=Bespoke]').prop('selected', true);
```